# Posting Network update to LinkedIn in PHP using Oauth2 access_token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Many code samples and tools for the LinkedIn REST API suppose that you have used Oauth1 to identify and that you consequently have obtained a Member Token and Member Secret.

Now, the sample code provided here by LinkedIn : http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples
enables to get an Oauth2 access_token.

Once you have the access_token, you can make query and get member's details using the fetch function provided in the code sample

```
function fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {


 $params = array('oauth2_access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token'],
                    'format' => 'json',
              );

    // Need to use HTTPS
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    // Tell streams to make a (GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE) request
    $context = stream_context_create(
                    array('http' =>
                        array('method' => $method,
                        )
                    )
                );


    // Hocus Pocus
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Native PHP object, please
    return json_decode($response);
}
```

OK, great, this works perfectly. But the prodived fetch function assumes that body is NULL.
But to post a Network update using [/v1/people/~/person-activities](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/post-network-update), you need to pass some XML in the body. I have tried many ways, found dozens of example using Oauth 1.0 member token and member secret. But I have not found any solution that works when you only have an Oauth2 access_token. So the question is :
What changes are required to this fetch function so that it can pass a XML body in the query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.

```
function GetXMLTemplate(){
   string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><activity locale="en_US">
   <content-type>linkedin-html</content-type>
   <body>xml_content</body>
   </activity>';
   return $string;
 }

 public function PostActivity($message) {   
    $details = $this->GetLinkedInDetails(); //own function returning basic details in Stdobject
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/
       person-activities?oauth2_access_token='.$this->access_token;
    // build your message
    $txt = '<a href="'.$details->siteStandardProfileRequest->url.'">'.$details->firstName.
           ' '.$details->lastName.'</a> '.$message;
    //the below str_replace is only required because the activity contains a <a> tag
    //if you don't have one, just keep the htmlspecialchars
    $txt = str_replace("&","&amp;",htmlspecialchars($txt,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,str_replace('xml_content',$txt,$this->GetXMLTemplate()));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml'));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($response);
    echo $http_status;
}
```

Comment: If you use json instead of XML you dont have to deal with XML and encodings. I made a slight improved version of the examples at linkedin, it provides really easy and painless integration, you can check it out if you like:
https://github.com/EJTH/SLinkedIn/blob/master/examples/share.php

Comment: LinkedIn recommends (http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/) using header-based authorization, as query strings may get logged in unsecure places. So I'd suggest removing `oauth2_access_token` from the URL and adding `'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->access_token` to the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` array.